# Canvas path commands vs SVG paths. Are they identical?

Tags: canvas, svg

Well long story short,

Can the canvas path drawing commands be converted to SVG path syntax?

Comment: Long answer short, yes. (but no, they're not identical)

Comment: @enhzflep long reply short, can they be converted ''trivially''? They sure look identical

Comment: SVG paths use both relative and absolute positioning/offsets. Canvas paths use absolute positioning. I'll leave it up to you to determine whether or not that's a trivial exercise. Why don't you write some code and experiment to see if you create a solution you find workable.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing now, I was just wondering if I would be able to save the hassle if they are absolutely not identical(no pun intented)

Comment: Aside from syntax they are functionally almost identical.  The notable difference is the arc command which is very different between svg and canvas.